# How did the syntactical strucutre “me gusta” come to be in Spanish? It seems to be different from its Latin root and other Romance languages

Tags: gramática, etimología, historia, comparación-de-idiomas, portugués

In Spanish there is the structure "Me gusta" where "Me" is the *object*. But in other Romance languages such as Portuguese "Eu gosto (de isso)" or French "Je goûterai le soir bleu", "eu" and "je" are the *subjects*. Those words seem to all have evolved from the Latin word "gustare", so why in Spanish the structure was changed? What could be the historical evolution of this expression?

Comment: Si no me equivoco, se da la misma diferencia entre el español _me gusta_ y el inglés _I like it_.

Comment: English has the same word, "gust", which is now obsolete, but the negative form, "disgust" is still in common usage and has the same form as in Spainsh (i.e. "Bananas disgust me"). So the answer to your question is basically "they're different verbs," and sadly has nothing to do with Spanish, *per se*. So I'm going to close this question as off-topic. But if you want to ask some other question specifically about Spanish and *gustar*, feel free.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about general verb forms, and not specific to Spanish.

Comment: What might make for a better question is asking why the Portuguese use of "gostar" changed from the French, Spanish, and English syntax... but of course that question would belong on [Portuguese.SE](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/). A survey of the other Romance languages' use of this word would also be interesting.

Comment: @Flimzy 1. I don't understand your point about them being two different words. As @TreeHouse196 clearly put below, they all originated from the same word *gustare* 2. I think you made a mistake here. **Spanish** is the exception, not Portuguese. In French the word is "goûter" and the dictionary *Multidictionnaire de la langue française* clearly states `3 (fig.)Apprécier. Goûter le calme de la forêt. | «Je goûterai le soir bleu» (Pierre Nepveu, Lignes aériennes).SYNONYME aimer; savourer.`

Comment: I'm not sure what I meant re: my point #1.  Re: the rest, I would encourage you to edit your question to focus on the Spanish etymology of the verb, rather than the comparison with Portuguese.

Comment: @Rodrigo Puede ser. Entonces mi pregunta es exactamente cómo se resultó/evolucionó esa diferencia.

Comment: See https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/20/5306.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider another sensory verb (because that's what *gustar* originated as) *oler*:

- Huelo algo terrible.
  <sup>I smell ( = *perceive sensorily*) something terrible</sup>
- Huelo a algo terrible
  <sup>I smell ( = *emit an odor*) something terrible.</sup>
- Algo me huele a algo terrible
  <sup>Something smells terrible to me == I smell something terrible</sup>

Notice how fluidly the meaning changes depending on whether there's a preposition or not, and then when used with an indirect object, there are two ways to interpret it.

At some point, *gustar* changed from meaning merely *to taste/experience* to pick up an enjoyable/pleasurable connotation (probably via the noun *gusto* with a likely semantic drift of *flavor → (good) taste → affinity*), at which *gustar* meant something akin to *tener/hacer gusto* rather than *saborear/probar*.  Consider the structures possible of *gustar* if we select different words along *gusto*'s semantic progression:

- Tengo gusto de algo
  <sup>I have an affinity for something</sup>
- Algo tiene gusto para mí.
  <sup>Something has a good taste for me.</sup>

To wit, in Modern Spanish, we have all of these meanings of *gusto* per the DRAE (23rd edition, ellipsis not noted):

> **gusto**: 3. Placer o deleite que se experimenta con algún motivo, o se recibe de cualquier cosa || 4. Facultad de sentir o apreciar lo bello o lo feo || 7. Cualidad, forma o manera que hace bello o feo algo || 12. Afición o inclinación por algo.

The traditional meaning of *gustar* is preserved in the transitive use of *gustar*:

- Gusto algo
  <sup>I try/taste something</sup>

The idea of providing such a pleasurable sensation (meanings 3 and 7, primarily) comes in the intransitive that virtually always comes with an indirect object:

- Me gusta algo
  <sup>Something has a nice quality / is pleasurable for me.</sup>

And then the meanings seen in 4 and 12 (being able to appreciate something or having an inclination towards it) also took an intransitive use, but with a *preposición de régimen*:

- Gusto de algo
  <sup>I appreciate / take pleasure in / am a connoisseur of something.</sup>

There's not a huge difference in practical meaning at the end of the day between the latter two uses, and it's probably random chance which language went which direction as its primary use.   Consider the modern languages of the Western Iberian branch of Romance languages:

- gosto de algo <sub>(PT)</sub>
- gusto de algo <sub>(GL)</sub>
- gusto d'algo <sub>(MWL)</sub>
- gústame dalgo <sub>(AST)<sup>1</sup></sub>
- me gusta algo <sub>(ES)</sub>

The Galician-Portuguese branch went with *gustar de* structure, the Castilian branch went with *gustarle* structure, and the Leonese branch split the difference.

Aragonese (also West Iberian) and Catalan (an Occitano-Romance language) ended up using a similar structure with indirect objects, but with different verbs — *m'agrada alguna cosa* <sub>(CAT)</sub>, *me faz goyo bella cosa* <sub>(AN)</sub> —<sup>2</sup> so it may simply be (though this would be speculation and also vastly over simplifying things) that Castilian ended up sandwiched between languages that preferred an indirect object to express the idea of liking something, and languages that liked to use the verb *gustar* to express that concept.

But remember that asking why when talking about changes in language is a relatively useless question.  The answer is almost "because that's what people said/did" :-)

---

<sup>**1.** The verb *prestar* is more common (*préstame dalgo*, "dalgo" is Asturian for "algo" and not a fusion of "de" and "algo"), but *gustar* does exit. **2.**  In Catalan *gustar* only has its transitive meaning of *to taste*, and Aragonese lacks *gustar* entirely (favoring *tastar*, which also exists in Catalan and used to exist in Castilian).</sup>

Answer (score 5):

In Spanish it is possible, although uncommon, for the word "gustar" to have the same syntax as in Portuguese. Here is a passage from the [Spanish Wiktionary article on gustar](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/gustar):

> Si se desea que la persona que siente el placer sea el sujeto, generalmente para usos literarios o cultos, el verbo va seguido de la preposición de: "gustamos de esa casa".
>
> *If it is desired that the person who feels the pleasure be the subject, generally for literary or educated uses, the verb is followed by the preposition de: "we like that house".*

Here is an example I found on [Google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=1SyAAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT23&lpg=PT23&dq=yo%20gusto,%20mia%20esposa,%20del%20contento&source=bl&ots=BmVeTmaSDJ&sig=JIwkgWSzkZl8FpTtSXo3UfsNX2c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMI1ursxOiCyQIVA9xjCh0GCwMI#v=onepage&q=yo%20gusto%2C%20mia%20esposa%2C%20del%20contento&f=false):

> Yo gusto, esposa mía, del contento que recibís en vuestras obras santas, y de ellas gano yo el merecimiento...

---

Unfortunately I cannot give a better answer. I am unable to find the origin of both uses of the word "gustar/gostar" to mean "to like". The word itself comes from the Latin word for "to taste", "*gustare*". I am also unable to find out which syntax of the verb "gustar/gostar" to mean "to like" originated first.

Answer (score 1):

John McWhorter [PhD Linguistics (Stanford)](https://americanstudies.columbia.edu/people/john-h-mcwhorter) expounds this:

[*The Power of Babel* (2003)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/006052085X), p. 125 Bottom.

> Another example is how languages mark subjects when the
>   topic has to do with experience rather than action. When we learn
>   Spanish, one construction we have to pause to wrap our heads
>   around is that *I like books* is *Me gustan los libros* “the books please me”
>   rather than what we would “ expect,” “Yo gusto los libros.” In Spanish, you say not that you like something but that it “ pleases to you,”
>   and thus “ to me please the books.” This is not a mere random
>   quirk— it follows from a distinction in types of object that English
>   just happens not to mark explicitly very much.
>     We get a handle on the distinction in question with the gustar
>   case: technically speaking, *books* in *I like books* is an “ object.” But
>   book is an object in a different way in *I like books* than in, say, *I read
>   books*. To like a book is not really to do anything to it-in contrast
>   with reading a book, you can like a book without touching it; if you
>   say you like a book, then you are actually describing a sentiment,
>   not an action. It is not accidental that Spanish has the “ to me” construction with *like*, a verb describing a kind of experience, and not
>   with, say, *drive*.

[*What Language Is* (2011)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592406254), [p. 24 Middle](https://books.google.com/books?id=xFQbHnvLonkC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=%22robust+in+its+germanic+relatives%22&source=bl&ots=o61SulUblG&sig=mqVqkEkgOK5-LwTrwsKB6tnmJrs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi51o6vouHbAhXCmVkKHQ2FDeAQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=manzanas&f=false).

> For an English speaker, for example, something always a 
>   nuisance in Spanish is how to say *like*. It comes out as that some-thing "pleases to you": *I like apples* is *Me gustan las manzanas*, 
>   "to-me please the apples." It's a very *specified* thing about Span-ish, attending to the technicality that while to eat something is 
>   to do something to it, to like it is to experience it—i.e., for some- 
>   thing to happen *to you*. The way an English speaker would like 
>   it to go is something like *Yo gusto las manzanas*, to bring it into 
>   line with our way of rendering liking, a less specified way of put- 
>   ting it. It's a typical Spanish-class mistake. But because a stu- 
>   dent has a teacher coaxing him out of it, *Yo gusto las manzanas* 
>   goes by the wayside pretty fast for someone in a Spanish class.